# More elegant way to selecting python popen process.kill() or process.terminate()

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, kill, terminate

I have small function that is designed for killing or terminating subproces and its subprocesses.

I am trying to write it in a more elegant way instead of repeating if, else twice.

```
def kill_process(cls, process, kill_type):
    process = psutil.Process(process.pid)

    for proc in process.children(recursive=True):

        if kill_type== 'terminate':

            proc.terminate()

        else:

            proc.kill()


    if kill_type== 'terminate':

        process.terminate()

    else:

        process.kill()
```

Comment: why don't you try terminate, wait a bit, then kill?

Comment: A simple helper method seems like it would do the trick, wouldn't it? `def kill_or_terminate(process, kill_type): <if/else statement here>`

Comment: I think OP wants to try to end the process nicely first, then if it doesn't respond, kill it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I actually don't get that impression at all from the question...maybe OP can clarify.

Comment: i run tcpdump, and if i do process.kill() i loose packet captured, received or dropped information. Which is why i need process.terminate().

If i run ffmpeg, i need process.kill() otherwise python is not able to end it. Which is why i need both depending if i want to kill ffmpeg or terminate tcpdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to not have the if/else statement twice, you could use a helper method:

```
def kill_or_terminate(proc, kill_type):
     if kill_type == 'terminate':
            proc.terminate()
        else:
            proc.kill()

def kill_process(cls, process, kill_type):
    process = psutil.Process(process.pid)

    for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
        kill_or_terminate(proc, kill_type)

    kill_or_terminate(process, kill_type)
```

Or add the parent process to the end of the list of children, so all the processes are in a single iterable:

```
def kill_process(cls, process, kill_type):
    process = psutil.Process(process.pid)
    for proc in process.children(recursive=True) + [process]:
        if kill_type == 'terminate':
            proc.terminate()
        else:
            proc.kill()
```

Comment: I have tried the 2nd example and it does exactly what i was looking for :). I have just added proc.wait()